# Overriding Payum Stripe Bundle templates

Tags: php, symfony, payum

I'm trying to customise the templates of [StripeBundle](https://github.com/PaymentSuite/StripeBundle), respectively the checkout template `vendor\payum\stripe\Payum\Stripe\Resources\views\Action\obtain_checkout_token.html.twig`.

This is because I want the Stripe popup to appear in the same page as the object that is paid for and not on a separate page with a single button. Say, I want to pay for a Product, I press 'pay' at the checkout page, and want the Stripe popup to appear there.

I took a look at [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24859255/2077972) but I can't seem to get it working. I've tried every single combination of folder names in `app/Resources` with PayumStripeBundle, Payum, Payum/Stripe, but none of them seem to override the used template.

The bundle's structure is also pretty strange, as its namespace is `Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle`, but the Stripe component which is not a bundle that contains the template is in another folder.

The value is set [here](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Factory/Gateway/StripeCheckoutGatewayFactory.php#L53), so maybe Symfony never looks in the folder because of that?

How should the folder structure in `app/Resources` be, if it works this way? Or if it's another way to do it.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your config.yml, and put an Action folder in that path with the templates you need.

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: ~
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../app/Resources/PayumBundle/Stripe/views": PayumStripe
```